Google-pay-button paymentRequest typeErrors when building
I've created this stackBlitz example where its building fine, no errors. I have uploaded this to a repository on github for me to clone and build locally or via github.dev /stackBlitz dev.
On each of those clones it throws typeErrors with the import { GooglePayButtonModule } from '@google-pay/button-angular';.
<google-pay-button environment="TEST" [paymentRequest]="paymentRequest" 
(loadpaymentdata)="onLoadPaymentData($event)"></google-pay-button>

It complains about the paymentRequest config:
  paymentRequest = {
    apiVersion: 2,
    apiVersionMinor: 0,
    allowedPaymentMethods: [
      {
        type: 'CARD',
        parameters: {
          allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY', 'CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'],
          allowedCardNetworks: ['AMEX', 'VISA', 'MASTERCARD'],
        },
        tokenizationSpecification: {
          type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
          parameters: {
            gateway: 'example',
            gatewayMerchantId: 'exampleGatewayMerchantId',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    merchantInfo: {
      merchantId: '12345678901234567890',
      merchantName: 'Demo Merchant',
    },
    transactionInfo: {
      totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
      totalPriceLabel: 'Total',
      totalPrice: '100.00',
      currencyCode: 'USD',
      countryCode: 'US',
    },
  };

Example of error from other IDEs...

Whats wrong and why does it work and not complain on stackBlitz?
Is there some setting in tsconfig I'm missing about strict typings, where StackBlitz is more sympathetic?

The error is coming from the below line.
✘ [ERROR] NG2: Type '{ apiVersion: number; apiVersionMinor: number; allowedPaymentMethods: { type: string; parameters: { allowedAuthMethods: string[]; allowedCardNetworks: string[]; }; tokenizationSpecification: { ...; }; }[]; merchantInfo: { ...; }; transactionInfo: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'PaymentDataRequest'.
  Types of property 'allowedPaymentMethods' are incompatible.
    Type '{ type: string; parameters: { allowedAuthMethods: string[]; allowedCardNetworks: string[]; }; tokenizationSpecification: { type: string; parameters: { gateway: string; gatewayMerchantId: string; }; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'PaymentMethodSpecification[]'.
      Type '{ type: string; parameters: { allowedAuthMethods: string[]; allowedCardNetworks: string[]; }; tokenizationSpecification: { type: string; parameters: { gateway: string; gatewayMerchantId: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'PaymentMethodSpecification'.
        Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'PaymentMethodType'. [plugin angular-compiler]

When I lookup the type of PaymentMethodType in DefinetlyTyped for google pay.
index.d.ts - github
type PaymentMethodType = "CARD" | "PAYPAL";

So you are passing value as string, but it is not matching with this type. To solve this problem, I first installed the typings for google pay from the below package:
@types/googlepay
npm install --save @types/googlepay

Then we can strict type the property which you pass as input to the google pay component.
  paymentRequest: google.payments.api.PaymentDataRequest = {
    apiVersion: 2,
    apiVersionMinor: 0,
    allowedPaymentMethods: [
      ...

Now your code should compile. The problem was the string you set 'CARD' was not recognized for the union type "CARD" | "PAYPAL", When we strict type the object, typescript recognizes the configuration and the error goes away.
Github Repo

Excellent. Thanks. I am just playing around at this point so this is a great answer for me.

That works. thanks again

Changing the tsconfig.ts file to not have strict templates solved the issue:
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": false << set to false here
  }

I guess stackblitz does not read this setting.

Could you try my setting, we can define the type of the object and keep this angular feature enabled, since it helps you detect errors in the application HTML sooner

Yes.. I will revert my change and try this out.
